# Support both JSON and XML as return type in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to enable web api to support both JSON and XML as return type. While serializing complex datattype to XML I got circular reference errors, so I decorated my main class with DataContract(IsReference = true), now XML serialization is working and json serialization not working.

thanks in advance.

PS: i am able to serialize simple dto classes to both xml and json, but for complex datatypes the problem is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result will be decided based on result type formatter. Hence I wrote 2 different methods for each return type. To solve, circular reference errors while generating xml i followed below steps.

1. Serialize class result
2. Deserialize class result.
3. Write it to xml.

   ```
       var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
       var rO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TClass>(json);
       return Ok(ReturnAsXml(rO), Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

       protected virtual XElement ReturnAsXml<T>(T data)
       {

           Type t = data.GetType();
           DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(t);//, extraTypes);
           StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
           XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
           serializer.WriteObject(xw, data);
           var o = XElement.Parse(sw.ToString());
           return o;
       }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Set the followings in `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs`

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Set `application/json` or `application/xml` to Accept header in request-side.

Comment: I able to generate json and xml for simple types. But for complex types I am getting issue.

Comment: Could you add your specific complex types to your question?